# I want to add one folder of javascript in my windows form application setup

Tags: .net, winforms

I am trying to add one folder of javascript in my  windows form application setup

but on doing or releasing setup it is not inlcuding that folder . i saw one option to add manually in the filesystem but JavaScript folder have many files ,If i want to add then i should do it manually .

Please help if there any other option to add those files in Windows form application setup folder

Comment: You can add this to the solution, and tell the IDE to copy the folder/contents to the output folder. No need to manually create it. I did the same with a few js/html files for .net communication to google maps.

Comment: How to tell the ide to copy ,actually it is working fine in debug mode but when i made setup it is not working , please give some refrence how to do it  or tell steps

Answer (score 0):

Which tool you are using for generating setup/installer?
You need to update your build script/installer code to copy that folder and its contents wherever required.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio to make setup  to make setup ,it is a windows form application

Comment: Right click your setup project -> View -> File System
Right click "File System on Target Machine" -> Add Special Folder -> "Custom Folder" context menu
Name the new folder whatever you like (e.g. BarSoftware)
Right Click new folder (e.g. BarSoftware) -> Add -> File
Add your JavaScript file

Comment: This thing i also know but js not contains only js file i have to add complete folder of themse skin etc , from this process you can only add files not any folders